# How to get a fraction of counters of subquery from different subqueries in one select?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with reviews for products. I want to sort product_ids that have more than 100 verified reviews(verified review is a review with verified_purshace=True) by the fraction of 5 star-reviews to all reviews. I tried to implement this in one select, but after numerous tries, I finish with the need to create views. I managed to write a query that counts a number of 5-star reviews, but can`t do better. Can anybody give me a hint?
My best query:

```
select *,count(*) 
from (
  select * 
  from reviews 
  where star_rating = 5
) low_reviews
  left join (
    select distinct filtered_reviews.product_id 
    from (
      select * 
      from (
        select verified_reviews.product_id, count(*) as verified_reviews_number  
        from (
          select * 
          from reviews 
          where verified_purchase=True
        ) as verified_reviews
      ) as counted_verified_reviews
      where counted_verified_reviews.verified_reviews_number > 100
    ) as filtered_reviews
  )  filtered_product_ids on low_reviews.product_id = filtered_product_ids.product_id;
```

Data example:

```
review_id  customer_id      product_id  star_rating  helpful_votes  total_votes  vine   verified_purshase  review_headline         review_body               review_date
14830128   R158AS05ZMH7VQ   0615349439  5            2              2            N      false              Planting a Church ...   Witnessing To Dracula...  2011-02-14
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Without those, your question is very hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to sort product_ids that have more than 100 verified reviews(verified review is a review with verified_purshace=True) by the fraction of 5 star-reviews to all reviews.

You don't provide sample data, but I would expect a query like this:

```
select product_id
from reviews
where verified_purchase
group by product_id
having count(*) > 100
order by avg( (review = 5)::int ) desc;
```

The expression `avg( (review = 5)::int )` is a shorthand way of saying `count(*) filter (where review = 5) * 1.0 / count(review)`.  It works because it converts the expression `review = 5` to an int, which is `1` for true and `0` for false.  The average is the proportion of times when it is true.

Actually, the above assumes that you only care about review start ratings for verified purchases.  If you want to include *all* reviews (even non-verified ones) for the ordering:

```
select product_id
from reviews
group by product_id
having count(*) filter (where verified_purchase) > 100
order by avg( (review = 5)::int ) desc;
```

Comment: I added a data example, please check it.

Comment: And also can you please explain what `avg( (review = 5)::int )` does? I can`t get it actually.